# Container tag that can go in HEAD?

Tags: asp.net, xhtml, standards

In a section in the `<head>` tags of my document I have code that lets me use the Id of my asp.net control from JavaScript like this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var customerId = '<%= Me.CustomerTextbox.ClientID %>';
</script>
```

However, if I want to modify the page structure in later stages of the page life cycle, it give me an error because I have the ASP tags in there. A work-around is enclosing the ASP tags in a server control like this:

```
<div id="customerIdContainer" runat="server">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var customerId = '<%= Me.CustomerTextbox.ClientID %>';
</script>
</div>
```

But then I get a warning that a div tag is not allowed in the head tag. So is there a container tag that is valid in the head that I can add runat="server" to to make it a server control so I can workaround this problem without the warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some thoughts:

- Can you just make "head" into "runat=sever"?
- If you use <asp:placeHolder id="whatever" runat="server" /> inside the head tag, will that complain?  If not, you can add controls to the placeholder from the code.
- Scripts can exist outside of the head tags, so just move it.

Answer (score 0):

Move the script tag outside the head section. ;-)